# If the Earth were a pool ball, could I feel mountains?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, earth, geometry, biophysics, estimation

If the earth (12,742 km diameter) were scaled down to the size of a pool ball (61mm diameter), the mountain ranges would still exist, obviously. But would a typical human be able to feel those mountains? Or even the mountain range as a whole? If not, how big would the earth have to be for me to feel that? Basketball? One of those stupid beach balls they throw around at concerts?

This probably will require a figure on exactly how sensitive the average human finger is. It also assumes I don't crush the earth with my massive hand, and that (magically) I don't disturb the oceans with, you know, gravity.

Comment: You could easily compute the size of the scaled down mountains, but for some reason that's not in the post. After that, look up the sensitivity of human fingers?

Comment: 30 km , difference between everest and a deept seabed ,  61mm * 30 km / 12742 km = 0.1436  mm. Are you able to feel 0.14 mm ? Yes, it is likely possible for a blind person

Comment: @igael - since that is thicker than a human hair - can you feel a human hair?

Comment: it is cylindric. Do you feel the draw on a piece of money ? It's of the same magnitude

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a physics question.

Answer (score 1):

If [this article](http://www.isciencetimes.com/articles/6073/20130917/sensitive-human-touch-new-research-suggests-fingers.htm) is to be believed, you would have no problem at all - in fact you could feel where the cities are, let alone the mountains.

Comment: it is credible. I roughly measured the relief of a coin from a photo. It is between 0.3 and 0.05 mm. I can feel it. The grooves ( around the coin ) are about 0.2 mm to 0.4 mm. I can feel them too